# Don't print in log

Tags: linux, shell, find

I need to print in file some information from a file tree. I need to list every file with `.rns` extension.

I try this:

```
find ./ -name "*.rns" -print>>myLog.log
```

and works great, but i'll like to put the system date before every line in log. Like this:

> 2013-10-02 14:02 - /volume1/file_1.rns

I try this but does not works:

```
FECHA=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`
VAR_FILE_INFO="$FECHA + `find ./ -name "*.rns"` "
echo "$VAR_PRUEBA"
```

That code return this:

```
2013-10-02 14:02 - /volume1/file_1.rns
/volume1/file_2.rns
/volume1/file_3.rns
/volume1/file_3.rns
```

Date is printed only one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
find ./ -name "*.rns" -printf "$FECHA %p\n" >> myLog.log
```

`%p` refers to the file name and `$FECHA` is the value you just stored. The last `\n` is to get a new line (otherwise all results would appear in the same line).

#### Test

```
$ FECHA=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`
$ find t/ -printf "$FECHA %p\n" >> mylog.log
$ cat mylog.log
2013-10-02 14:27 t/
2013-10-02 14:27 t/myfile
2013-10-02 14:27 t/mydir
2013-10-02 14:27 t/mydir/something
```

---

> It seem does not work. Maybe is because i'm testing in Unix not Linux find: bad option -printf

Then you can do it as follows:

```
for file in $(find ./ -name "*.rns")
do
  echo "$FECHA $file" >> myLog.log
done
```

Or, better:

```
while read -r file;
do
  echo "$FECHA $file" >> myLog.log
done < <(find ./ -name "*.rns")
```

Comment: `%f => %p` & then I'll delete my answer ;)

Comment: @Wrikken thank you! That's very kind of you :) I thought it was `%f`.

Comment: Hehe, I had to look it up too, tested with %f before answering & noticed the leading dirs were missing ;)

Comment: It seem does not work. Maybe is because i'm testing in Unix not Linux find: bad option -printf

Comment: @user2838545 check my updated answer, it might work.

Comment: I think for efficiency's sake, I would prefer `find ./ -name "*.rns" | sed -e "s/^/${FECHA} /"` over the `for` loop with repeated open/close cycles on the log. Or, at least, put the `>> myLog.log` after `done` instead...

Comment: Thanks a lot @twalberg but i'm deleting the files i found. I don't know it is will work with your solution. I have the code like this right now: for file in $(find ./ -name "*.rns")
do
  FECHA=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
  echo "$     FECHA - Fichero $file eliminado" >> $LOG
  rm $file
done

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a loop:

```
FECHA=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`
for f in `find ./ -name "*.rns"`; do
     echo "$FECHA - $f" >> myLog.log
done
```

Does it help?

Comment: Thank you, I need to scan subfolders too because this I used find command.